Buid System - getting installed relative path
I have a simple question: how can I obtain a LazyPath for an installed file after using for examplestd.Build.addInstallFile() function?
Context:
I need to construct a complex argument for another system command (addSystemCommand()). For instance, examine this code snippet:
qemu_iso_action.addArg(try std.fmt.allocPrint(b.allocator, "file={s},format=qcow2,if=none,id=drv0", .{installed_disk_img_file_path_str}));

Here, installed_disk_img_file_path_str needs to be assigned a value coming from std.Build.addInstallFile()

Are you looking for this

It seems to be missing a LazyPath, you have to call getInstallPath(self.dir, self.dest_rel_path) directly. Which is good because you can't add an argument to a run command that contains a lazy path surrounded by text, only a lazy path prefixed by text

OK, for now and thanks to @user459872 and @pfg we can proceed this either like:
qemu_iso_action.addArg(try std.fmt.allocPrint(b.allocator, "file={s}/{s},format=qcow2,if=none,id=drv0", .{b.install_prefix, bebok_disk_img_filename}));

or
qemu_iso_action.addArg(try std.fmt.allocPrint(b.allocator, "file={s},format=qcow2,if=none,id=drv0", .{b.getInstallPath(.prefix, bebok_disk_img_filename)}));

